# iMacros - conditional based on URL

Tags: imacros

Our website uses A/B testing on one of our online application forms.  Form A has 6 extra fields than form B.

iMacros is invauable for testing these forms, but it breaks when form B shows up and it tries to access one of the fields that only exists in form A.

how do I do this:

```
if (url=/applicationform1) {
  TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT ATTR=ID:HouseholdContentsInsured CONTENT=%no
}
```

basically "if form A, then try to populate the field, otherwise ignore"

Answer (score 0):

Let's say form A has 10 fields and form B has 6.

```
var macroFields;

macroFields ="CODE:";
macroFields +="SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 0"+"\n";
macroFields +="TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT ATTR=ID:HouseholdContentsInsured CONTENT=EVENT:MOUSEOVER"+"\n";
var counter=1;

while(true)
{

iimSet("n",counter)
var ret=iimPlay(macroFields);

if(ret<0)
{
break;
}
else
{
counter++;
}

}//end of while loop


if(counter>6)
{
//fill form A
}
else if(counter<=6)
{
//fill form B
}
```

What will this do is count the number of fields on the form. If the number is greater then 6 then you can put the A filling macro in proper place and it will be played. But if the number is 6 or less then you can put the B filling macro in proper place.